# Why QAction is not adding to QMenu, if QMenu is unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, qt

Code example:

```
auto fileMenu = std::make_unique<QMenu>(this->menuBar()->addMenu("First"));
fileMenu->addAction("AFirst");

auto x = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Second");
x->addAction("ASecond");
```

Results:

I have 2 menus in menubar, but in first menu - for some reason, there are NO actions. Second menu correctly has action.

I have tried different approaches, like, class-member pointers, and so on, but this is shortest possible example - QAction is missing, if QMenu is unique_ptr. Can anyone explain this for me? Parent window is QMainWindow, just in case.

System info:
Win8.1 x64, Compiler is VS2013, Qt 5.4 x32.

Comment: Hmm. I expect using std::unique_ptr for this to lead to a double delete since Qt will delete the child when the parent goes out of scope.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the `QMenu` in a `unique_ptr`; it is already managed by the menu bar.

Comment: QAction is not wrapped, QMenu is wrapped here.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.  I was looking at the other overload for `addMenu` in the documentation, the one that returns a `QAction`.

Comment: Did your std::unique_ptr fileMenu go out of scope? Perhaps your fileMenu is already freed however still connected to the parent and you are experiencing UB.

Comment: I've tried to make uniqueptr as classmember, so, it won't go out of scope - result is the same

Comment: It's not a double delete anyhow; if you delete a children, it will get removed from its parent. It might be a case of plain deletion when the `unique_ptr` falls out of scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
auto fileMenu = std::make_unique<QMenu>(this->menuBar()->addMenu("First"));
```

`fileMenu` becomes a new `QMenu` object (using [this constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#QMenu)). It's quite the same as:

```
std::unique_ptr<QMenu> fileMenu(new QMenu(this->menuBar()->addMenu("First")));
```

Then, you add an `QAction` to this temporary, new menu.

In the second case:

```
auto x = this->menuBar()->addMenu("Second");
x->addAction("ASecond");
```

`x` become a pointer to existing menu. That's the difference.

Anyway, usually you shouldn't hold `QObject`s using `std::unique_ptr`. In Qt, there is a convention that you form a tree from `QObject`s by assigning parent to each of them. The parent deletes it's children recursively and you shouldn't manage them manually or you may cause double free in some specific cases.

Comment: You're not explaining why the first way doesn't work and the second way works, though...

Comment: @peppe: "Then, you add an QAction to this temporary, new menu." Isn't it obvious that inserting QAction to a temporary object does not insert it to `menuBar`?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly a "temporary". `QMenuBar::addMenu` will create a new `QMenu` as a child, and return it. Then the real problem is that `unique_ptr` is going to destroy that `QMenu` when `fileMenu` falls out of scope. OP also said *"tried to make uniqueptr as classmember, so, it won't go out of scope - result is the same"*, but I haven't seen the updated code.

Comment: @peppe: Ok, it's not "temporary" in C++ meaning. It's just a new object, which is not a submenu. It's a **child of** `QMenu` returned by `QMenuBar::addMenu`. It seems, that simply creating a `QMenu` with another `QMenu` as a parent doesn't make it a submenu. Even if it wasn't managed with `unique_ptr` it wouldn't work as expected.